# SocketException: Connection failed (OS Error: Network is unreachable, errno = 101), address = 18.191.190.195, port = 80

Tags: http, dart, flutter

Flutter/Dart

Why does `http.get('http://18.191.190.195/')` throw above error while using chrome browser http://18.191.190.195/ shows the Test Page and says: 
If you can read this page, it means that the Apache HTTP server installed at this site is working properly.

Answer (score -1):

Cause: Poor network connection. 
Suggestion: Error reporting should be more descriptive from Dart.